# how to get Latest date from table in oracle procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to fetch the data with latest date in oracle procedure

```
            BEGIN
                SELECT NVL(MONTHLY_SAL, 0)
                  INTO v_emp_salary
                  FROM EMP_SALARY
                 WHERE EMPNO = file_row(k).EMPNO
                 AND LATEST DATE = file_row(k).MODDATE; 
             EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                  v_emp_salary := 0;
             END;
```

Here EMP_SALARY might have 2 or more rows i need to compare MODDATE with latest date in EMP_SALARY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using MAX()?

```
select * from oehr_employees WHERE HIRE_DATE = (SELECT MAX(HIRE_DATE) FROM OEHR_EMPLOYEES)
```

OUTPUT:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                 EMAIL                     PHONE_NUMBER         HIRE_DATE JOB_ID         SALARY COMMISSION_PCT MANAGER_ID DEPARTMENT_ID

167 Amit    Banda   ABANDA  011.44.1346.729268  21-APR-00   SA_REP  6200    0.1 147 80
173 Sundita Kumar   SKUMAR  011.44.1343.329268  21-APR-00   SA_REP  6100    0.1 148 80
```